# Laravel - Function requests not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have passed same request parameters of dates to index and list functions. parameters are displaying in index function but not in lists function.
What am i doing wrong?
Code is attached

```
public function index(Request $request){

    ....

    $from_date = $request->input('from_date') ? : '';
    $to_date = $request->input('to_date') ? : '';

    return view('payroll.index',compact('col_heads','from_date', 'to_date', 'menu','table_info'));
}

public function postPayrollList(PostPayrollRequest $request){
    $response = ['message' => trans('messages.request_submit'), 'status' => 'success'];
    return response()->json($response, 200, array('Access-Controll-Allow-Origin' => '*'));
}

public function lists(PostPayrollRequest $request){
    ....
        $from_date = $request->input('from_date') ? : '';
        $to_date = $request->input('to_date') ? : '';
        ....
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/payroll','PayrollController@index');
Route::post('/payroll', array('as'=>'payroll.index','uses'=>'PayrollController@postPayrollList'));
Route::post('/payroll/lists','PayrollController@lists');
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Am i doing something wrong? i have attached the code can you find any mistake?

Comment: Show us `PostPayrollRequest`

Comment: Share your error screenshot.

Comment: You can't display your "lists", because you have no `get` method on your lists route

Comment: PostPayrollRequest extends Illuminate\Http\Request; ?